# Экспоненциальный рост времени выполнения цикла

Tags: java, алгоритм

Есть некий лист forReport, со списком объектов, и нужно достать из него уникальные значения по полю и записать их в качестве ключа в Map, а в качестве значения этому ключу присвоить лист объектов который содержит это самое поле
в данном случае IdPoint

```
Map<String,List<ProductEntity>> forTwoTable = new HashMap<>();
    List<ProductEntity> tmpList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(ProductEntity obj : forReport){
        tmpList.clear();
        for(ProductEntity entity : forReport){
            if(ForM.getNameById(obj.getIdPoint().getIdPoint()).equals(ForM.getNameById(entity.getIdPoint().getIdPoint()))){
                tmpList.add(entity);
            }
        }
        if (!forTwoTable.containsKey(ForM.getNameById(obj.getIdPoint().getIdPoint()))){
            countPoint++;
            forTwoTable.put(ForM.getNameById(obj.getIdPoint().getIdPoint()),tmpList);
        }
    }
```

Объект класса ProductEntity примерного содержания

```
int id;
PointsEntity idPoint;
String product;
BigDecimal price;
BigDecimal brutto;
BigDecimal summ;
```

При кол-ве обьектов(размере forReport) до ~100 работает ещё более менее быстро, но нужно обрабатывать более тысячи таких обьектов.
Как можно улучшить этот алгоритм?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Слово "работает" в отношении Вашего кода можно употребить только в смысле "жжет электричество".

Это делается за один проход, и для каждого ключа нужен свой список:

```
Map<String,List<ProductEntity>> forTwoTable = new HashMap<>();
List<ProductEntity> tmpList;
for(ProductEntity obj : forReport){
    String name = ForM.getNameById(obj.getIdPoint().getIdPoint());
    if (!forTwoTable.containsKey(name)) {
      tmpList = new List<ProductEntity>();
      forTwoTable.put(name, tmpList);
    } else {
      tmpList = forTwoTable.get(name);
    }
    tmpList.add(obj);
}
```

Comment: У HashMap `[]` или `put`/`get`?

Comment: @Qwertiy - понятия не имею. В тагах стоит - "алгоритм".

Comment: В его коде `put` и это джава, а в ней нет перегрузки операторов - так что я сомневаюсь, что она умеет квадратные скобки с чем-то кроме массивов.

Comment: @Qwertiy - ну не в этом же дело! заменит скобки на put/get, неужели это так трудно?

Comment: ну я исправил две строки  forTwoTable[name] = tmpList; на forTwoTable.put(name,tmpList);

Comment: и tmpList = forTwoTable[name]; на tmpList = forTwoTable.get(name);

Comment: Согласен, не в этом. Но всё-таки не очень хорошо, когда код из ответа не компилируется, тем более, если он в целом правильный :)

Comment: @Qwertiy - Согласен, поправил.